# How to execute part of the code in ESS (Emacs speaks statistics)

Tags: matlab, emacs, region, ess

In matlab script editor, we can use double percent symbol to define a region. for example in the following matlab script, two region are defined:

```
%% region 1
a=1;
b=2;
%% region 2
c=7;
d=5;
```

The advantage of defining region is that you can just execute one region where the cursor locates rather than the whole script by press ctrl+enter.

if the cursor is at c=7; line, after pressing ctrl+enter, c=7 and d=5 will be executed while  a=1 and b=2 will not be executed.

however, I have searched a lot from web to find something equivalent in ESS, there is no results.

There is a command 'eval region' in ESS, but I don't know how to define such a region.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The region is emacs speak for the part of the text that you would (essentially) consider to be "highlighted" in a "normal"/GUI text editor.

You can read more about it in [The Mark and the Region](http://sunsite.univie.ac.at/textbooks/emacs/emacs_12.html) in the [emacs manual](http://sunsite.univie.ac.at/textbooks/emacs/emacs_toc.html).

As far as I know, there is no equivalent to the matlab behavior you are describing. The few times I have used matlab, though, I do recall finding it handy when poking at a problem using *ad hoc* scripts.

Comment: probably making a temporary ad hoc scripts for particular problem would be a good idea at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

As Steve said select a region, then all the standard ESS evaluation commands will act on a region (<kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>,<kbd>C-RET</kbd>,<kbd>C-M-x</kbd>).

But, what you describe sounds very interesting. Would you mind giving the full description of the workflow and markup, and post it to ess-help mailing list for a more thorough discussion? I would be interested in implementing such a feature. Thanks.

Comment: To prime the pump, [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/run-sections-of-programs.html) is the documentation page for the feature being discussed here. You can see a relatively small script there in the "Example of Evaluating Code Sections" section that shows the behavior. It's a cute trick, but some might consider it a poorman's version of Rmarkdown ;-)

Comment: @SteveLianoglou Thanks. Matlab's implementation deeply integrates with the parser and recognize nesting levels. In emacs top level regions are easily implementable. I have added this to our todo.